# Visual Studio invalid rule The enum member 'NewProducts' has the same constant value '6' as member 'NewProducts'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, enums, roslyn-code-analysis

ASP.NET Core 5 MVC shopping cart application defines enum in controllers namespace like this:

```
namespace Store.Controllers
{
    public enum FixedCategories
    {
        NewProducts = 6
    }
}
```

Visual Studio 2019 shows strange hint about this

> The enum member 'NewProducts' has the same constant value '6' as member 'NewProducts'

Enum integer value 6 is stored in database and used to compare with this enum vale. So it must be 6.

https://learn.microsoft.com/et-ee/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1069

states that this is caused by duplicate enum value and

> Do not suppress violations of this rule.

As seen in code, enum contains only single member. So it cannot be duplicate.

Why is VS complaining about this? How to fix it?

Quick action button does not show any reasonable fix.

[image]

Comment: I've seen this also & been a bit confused, so your not alone. A bug I assumed.

Comment: Which version of VS is used? There is the similar [open issue](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/15815)

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019  Version 16.8.5

Comment: Nice the issue I filed 7 days ago got linked in stackoverflow. This is nice.

Comment: I am also using Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.8.5, and try to define the FixedCategories enum in the Controller namespace, but it seems that everything works well and can't reproduce the problem. Try to create new web application to test it. If it works well, try to clear your application and rebuild it.

Comment: @PSXGamerPro1 After re-starting  Visual Studio this issue does not appear anymore